# Standard Solution for orderless XSD sequences

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xjc

I'm encountering an interesting obstacle when it comes to generating classes through an XSD and reading them through moxy (probably unrelated to the issue).  I have an element with several underlying elements, several of which occuring 0 to N times, a couple occuring at most once, and one or two that must always being supplied.

The standard solution for this is through a sequence:

```
<xs:complexType name="element1">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="element2" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="element3" type="element3Type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="element4" type="xs:boolean" default="false" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="element5" type="element5Type" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="element6" type="element6Type" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="element7" type="element7Type" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="element8" type="element7Type" minOccurs="0" />

        <xs:element name="element9" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="element10" type="xs:short" />
                    <xs:element name="element11" type="xs:short" />
                    <xs:element name="element12" type="xs:short" />
                    <xs:element name="element13" type="xs:short" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="element14" type="element5Type" minOccurs="0" />

        <xs:element name="element15" type="element7Type" minOccurs="0" />

        <xs:element name="element16" type="element16Type" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="element17" type="element16Type" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

As you can see - complicated.  Our users are having a lot of trouble scripting or writing against our service by hand because it can be hard to remember what order everything **must** go in that order or else parsing through moxy fails. I *believe* it's due to the `@xmlType(propOrder=...)` attribute that xjc slaps on the generated classes. As a result, our users hate it, want it changed, and I don't blame them.

Obviously, we can't replace `<xsd:sequence />` with `<xsd:all />` because of the variance in element frequency.

I'm starting to suspect that it's not the constraints of the XSD, but possibly in our overall approach to this sort of configuration.

Based on that, is there a standard approach to this sort of problem that we aren't considering? What is the most appropriate solution?

Answer (score 0):

XSD 1.1 allows `xs:all` with occurrence limits other than [0,1] and [1,1].

Comment: You had me all sorts of excited... until I found out that xjc still doesn't support it, despite it coming out in 2012 and the community begging for it. Thanks for the heads up with 1.1, though.

Comment: I'm afraid the "community" got rather hooked on all the free XML software that came out 20 years ago, and most of the suppliers of such software weren't able to construct a business case for producing new versions. Paying for it rather than begging might have been more effective.